# Using ADB to capture the screen

Tags: android, adb, screenshot

I'm trying to get a screenshot of the phone screen as fast as possible.
Currently, I am doing:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screencap.png && adb pull /sdcard/screencap.png
```

However it is too slow and takes up to 3 seconds.
Is there any better way to do this? I intend to use this function with an unrooted phone.

Also what are the different arguments I can use for screencap?

Thanks.

EDIT (extra information): I intend to use this method to be able to get a live feed of the screen onto my pc. The current method works however it is too slow. I can't use `adb shell screenrecord` because I won't be able to access the video file while it is being recorded.

Comment: Why is 3s slow for you? What is your intention to do with this?

Comment: I intended to get a live feed of the screen onto my pc.. Is this a stupid way of doing this? `adb shell screenrecord` was an option but it wouldn't be able to be accessed during the recording.

Comment: Do you need a live feed of only one application (that you develop), or it should work for anything that is running on that device?

Comment: It should work for anything.

Comment: Then screenrecord should be your solution. Did you check this http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord ?
I have used Android Studio to record and I guess it uses the same thing. I was able to use the device while recording the screen. What device do you use for this and what OS version is there?

Comment: This has been covered before.  You may want to look into retutning the data through an adb forward.

Comment: helleye: I mean I wouldn't be able to grab the video file while it is being recorded as it blocks until you Ctrl-C or the time limit is hit.

Comment: Chris: It's the actual screencap function that takes time, not the `adb pull` as that completes in roughly 0.5s

Comment: Right, I forgot about that, sorry. Have you seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25859066/2160877 ?
BTW, you don't just need to show it on a bigger screen, right? Because if that was the case you could use a monitor or TV as a secondary output screen (like HDMI).

Comment: You should update your question with the details you have shared in the comments (and add more if necessary) so that others(that don't read the comments here) will have a better understanding what you are asking for.

Comment: Yeah okay, also I want to do more than just see the screen. I want to be able to use the mouse to tap the screen as well but I have that figured out (`adb shell tap x y`)

Also that answer from that link: I can't pull from /dev/graphics/fb0 because it says that it is a special file (folder). It might have something to do with the phone being a Samsung device but it is out of the option.

Comment: I realise this is old, and I can't add an answer now, but I've been using scrcopy (https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to mirror the device to desktop,  then using Windows APIs to capture the screen. This method takes about .2 seconds per capture.

Comment: I found this simple (no external dependencies) solution that uses ffplay: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/154328/283532

Comment: Windows Powershell: adb shell screencap /sdcard/screenshot.png; adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.png screenshot.001.png

(question is locked)

Comment: +1 to [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) as mentioned by IanNewson  if, as per the EDIT, _"I intend to use this method to be able to get a live feed of the screen onto my pc"_. OP mentions nothing about wanting to process the frames.

Comment: [Vysor](https://www.vysor.io/) is another (commercial) option for mirroring Android devices.

Answer (score 368):

To save to a file on Windows, OSX and Linux

```bash
adb exec-out screencap -p > screen.png
```

To copy to clipboard on Linux use

```bash
adb exec-out screencap -p | xclip -t image/png
```

Comment: This works in Linux too.

Comment: I get "The file "screen.png" could not be opened." when I try to open it.

Comment: What about Windows OS?

Comment: Btw, because I use this frequently for sharing with designers and for product tutorials, I created a bash alias in my `~/.bash_profile` that looks like this: `alias adb_screenshot="adb -d shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > $(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S").png"`. You call it with `adb_screenshot` in the terminal and it will save a .png file with the current timestamp as the filename. The `-d` option in the `adb` command means it will default to physical device (not the emulator). You can remove that if you are using this for an emulator.

Comment: For macOS:  `adb exec-out screencap -p > test.png`

Comment: For macOS 10.13.1 .`adb exec-out screencap -p > screen.png` got error. And @JoshuaPinter works!

Comment: it works on Windows 10

Comment: This is very nice, yet overwrites the same file again and again. This variant writes several files with names arranged to be in correct order whatever (sane) program you use to browse them: `adb exec-out screencap -p > android_screenshot_"$( date +%Yy%mm%dd_%Hh%Mm%Ss )".png`

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Your alias would be better as `alias adb_screenshot="adb -d exec-out screencap -p > $(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S").png"` - that regex can corrupt the file if there is a valid 0x0D 0x0A sequence in the png data.

Comment: @nevelis You're right! Just tried my command and it resulted in a corrupt file but yours worked perfectly. Thanks! You should add it as an answer so people can find it. It's great.

Comment: Any reason it should not work on the other platform, than mentioned ones? It works, naturally, on Windows.

Comment: this doesn't work. results in invalid file.

Comment: What is the difference between `exec-out screencap -p` and `shell screencap -p`?

Comment: For macOS copy-to-clipboard you can this tool that wraps adb `npx android-capture image --copy`

Comment: Figured I'd post an update here since my last post was well liked but is now outdated. Here is what we're using now, which takes a screenshot of all the devices attached (very useful for those working with multiple devices) and saves the screenshots with the serial number of each device and current timestamp. Enjoy. `adb devices -l | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c "adb -s {} exec-out screencap -p > {}_$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').png"`

Comment: For Windows users: Run the command in CMD, not PowerShell (or run `cmd` in PowerShell). PowerShell is corrupting the binary data when creating the file (it is interpreting the piped PNG image data as text).

Comment: Is this exclusively from adb? I tried from the actual phone (on 2 different devices) with a terminal app with `$ screencap test.png` and it generates a 0 byte file. The folder is writable, for example `echo hello > test.txt` does create a 6 byte file

Comment: Revising Joshua's revised code, `adb devices -l` now returns `List of devices attached` at least on macOS. This revised command deletes that first line of the output. `adb devices -l | cut -d' ' -f1 | tail -n +2| xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c "adb -s {} exec-out screencap -p > {}_$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').png"`

Comment: For those wanting to use PowerShell, call via CMD using `cmd /c 'adb exec-out screencap -p > .\pic3.png'` ( [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72021041/p-in-powershell-from-adb/72021532#72021532) )

Answer (score 23):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37191719/75579 answer stopped working for me in Android 7 somehow. So I have to do it the manual way, so I want to share it.

---

#### How to install

1. Put this snippet of code in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` file:

   ```
   snap_screen() {
     if [ $# -eq 0 ]
     then
       name="screenshot.png"
     else
       name="$1.png"
     fi
     adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/$name
     adb pull /sdcard/$name
     adb shell rm /sdcard/$name
     curr_dir=pwd
     echo "save to `pwd`/$name"
   }
   ```
2. Run `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.profile` command,

---

#### How to use

Usage without specifying filename:

```
$ snap_screen
11272 KB/s (256237 bytes in 0.022s)
Saved to /Users/worker8/desktop/screenshot.png
```

Usage with a filename:

```
$ snap_screen mega_screen_capture
11272 KB/s (256237 bytes in 0.022s)
Saved to /Users/worker8/desktop/mega_screen_capture.png
```

Hope it helps!

** This will not work if multiple devices are plugged in

Comment: This just moves a file around... doesn't actually take a screenshot?

Comment: @Karu oh no, you're so right, I somehow left out the important line, I just fixed it!

Comment: thanks @dragonwhospitsfire !

Answer (score 13):

To start recording your device’s screen, run the following command:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/example.mp4
```

This command will start recording your device’s screen using the default settings and save the resulting video to a file at /sdcard/example.mp4 file on your device.

When you’re done recording, press Ctrl+C in the Command Prompt window to stop the screen recording. You can then find the screen recording file at the location you specified. Note that the screen recording is saved to your device’s internal storage, not to your computer.

The default settings are to use your device’s standard screen resolution, encode the video at a bitrate of 4Mbps, and set the maximum screen recording time to 180 seconds. For more information about the command-line options you can use, run the following command:

```
adb shell screenrecord --help
```

This works without rooting the device. Hope this helps.

Comment: I won't be able to get a live feed of the video unless the file is being recorded directly to my pc. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: It says an error WorkingDirectoty: null Environment: null

Answer (score 9):

You can read the binary from stdout instead of saving the png to the sdcard and then pulling it:

```
adb shell screencap -p | sed 's|\r$||' > screenshot.png
```

This should save a little time, but not much.

source: [Read binary stdout data from adb shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578416/read-binary-stdout-data-from-adb-shell)

Comment: Thanks Jared--unfortunately Diego's answer did not work for me, but yours did.

Comment: I get an error: "sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence" when I try this.

Comment: This always worked for me, but I just had to change this to `sed 's|\r\r$||'` (to remove TWO carriage returns) because I started getting corrupt PNGs. Not sure what changed (New version of ADB? New version of cygwin?) but something did.

Comment: I am getting `PNG file corrupted by ASCII conversion` when opening the PNG file.

Answer (score 6):

Using some of the knowledge from this and a couple of other posts, I found the method that worked the best for me was to:

`adb shell 'stty raw; screencap -p'`

I have posted a very simple Python script on GitHub that essentially mirrors the screen of a device connected over ADB:

https://github.com/baitisj/android_screen_mirror

Comment: no need to use `stty`. use `adb exec-out` instead. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31401447/1778421

Comment: Unfortunately, the version of `adb` that I have either does not properly support `exec-out`, or the option isn't properly supported under FreeBSD. The script that I posted does include comments indicating that `exec-out` is a better choice if it is supported in your environment.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to tell you `screencap` just a simple command, only accept few arguments, but none of them can save time for you, here is the `-h` help output.

```
$ adb shell screencap -h
usage: screencap [-hp] [-d display-id] [FILENAME]
-h: this message
-p: save the file as a png.
-d: specify the display id to capture, default 0.
If FILENAME ends with .png it will be saved as a png.
If FILENAME is not given, the results will be printed to stdout.
```

Besides the command `screencap`, there is another command `screenshot`, I don't know why `screenshot` was removed from `Android 5.0`, but it's avaiable below `Android 4.4`, you can check the source from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/android-4.4_r1/cmds/screenshot/). I didn't make my comparison which is faster between these two commands, but you can give your try in your real environment and make the final decision.

Comment: Thanks for that. Turns out the screenshot function is the actual device screenshot function (where it can play a sound) whereas screencap just takes a screenshot silently. It doesn't look like it's any faster but thanks anyway.

Comment: You might use the stdout to transfer the file directly to the pc