# -p in powershell from adb

Tags: windows, powershell, adb

Hey im trying to do a screenshot from "Mobilephone" from the terminal
I can pull and push normally but when I use the command

```
.\adb exec-out screencap -p > ./pic3.png
```

The png cant open

Comment: You mean like this?`:
.\adb exec-out screencap -p  stackoverflow.png

Comment: You cannot use `>` (or `<` or `|`, for that matter) in PowerShell for binary data. Use cmd or bash instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing (PowerShell 7.2.2), **PowerShell's `>` operator is fundamentally incapable of capturing *raw bytes* (binary output)** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375) for more information.

The simplest workaround is to call via `cmd.exe`, whose `>` operator *does* support raw byte streams:

```
cmd /c 'adb exec-out screencap -p > .\pic3.png'
```

The alternative is to save the screenshot directly to a file on the Android device (syntax gleaned from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#screencap)), and download it afterwards, as you show [in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72022530/45375).

```
.\adb shell screencap ./pic3.png
```

Comment: Yeah it works but in cmd without point before adb

cmd /c db exec-out screencap -p > .\pic3.png'

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @ProAslan. As an aside: If `adb.exe` is located in the current directory, `.\adb` should work from `cmd.exe` too (but _not_ `./adb` with a _forward_ slash). In PowerShell, _both_ `.\adb` and `./adb` work, but _not_ `adb` (without a path), because PowerShell by security-minded design doesn't allow executing executables located in the current directory by name only.

Answer (score 1):

Ok if I use

```
.\adb shell screencap ./pic3.png
```

in shell, then I can pull it with

```
.\adb pull sdcard/download/pic3.png
```

Comment: I see - I missed that the command saves the screenshot to a file _on the Android device_. Please see my update, which shows a simpler alternative via `cmd /c`