# Capture screen from Nox Player

Tags: android-emulator, adb, screenshot

I have the idea of writing a bot to play games in NoxPlayer. Currently, I am stumbling on capturing a screenshot from Nox with `adb -e shell screencap -p screen.png` with the error `Read-only file system`. I did start Nox with the root access and turned on debugging mode in the Developer option. What do I have to do to capture a screen from NoxPlayer?

Comment: Instead of saving the screen shot inside the emulator you can transfer and store in on PC side: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31401447/150978

Comment: If screencap is not fast enough for your task take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984854/236465